# jQuery Validate and WP-Pointers

Tags: jquery-validate

I was looking at the possibility of using WP-Pointers for displaying validation errors generated by jQuery Validation Plugin.

This is how the WP-Pointer javascript looks like:

```
$('.selector').pointer({
    content: '<h3>Error</h3><p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>',
    position: 'right',
    close: function() {

    }
}).pointer('open');
```

This is how validation javascript looks like:

```
$('.registration-form').validate({
debug                   : true,
rules                   : { username    : {required: true, minlength: 4},
                            email       : {required: true, email: true}
},
messages                : { username    : 'Username must be atleast 4 characters long.',
                            email       : 'Please enter a valid email address.'
},
errorLabelContainer     : '.message-box',
submitHandler           : function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success         : show_registration_response,
        url             : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
        type            : 'POST',
        timeout         : 10000,
        clearForm       : true,
        resetForm       : true
    }); 
}
});
```

I was wondering if the WP-Pointer script could be passed as a function or something inside the validation script to display the error messages as WP-Pointers?

Comment: Got this resolved. However, unable to post an answer until next 7-8 hours as I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped the WP-Pointer script as a callback inside invalidHandler option of jQuery Validate. Also, specified the errorPlacement option with no callback to stop display of errors next to the elements.

```
$('.registration-form').validate({
debug           : true,
rules           : { username    : {required: true, minlength: 4},
                    email       : {required: true, email: true}
},
messages        : { username    : 'Username must be atleast 4 characters long.',
                    email       : 'Please enter a valid email address.'
},
invalidHandler  : function(form, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        $(validator.errorList[0].element).pointer({
                            content: '<h3>Error</h3><p>' + validator.errorList[0].message + '</p>',
                            position: 'top',
                            close: function() {
                                // This function is fired when you click the close button
                            }
                        }).pointer('open');

                        validator.errorList[0].element.focus(); //Set focus
                    }
},
errorPlacement  : function(error, element) {

},
submitHandler   : function(form) {
                    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        success         : show_registration_response,
                        url             : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
                        type            : 'POST',
                        timeout         : 10000,
                        clearForm       : true,
                        resetForm       : true
                    });
}
});
```